# How to define alternate XML structures in XSD schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

How do you define alternate XML structures in xsd schema? For example the next structures would be optional:

```
<a>
  <b/>
  <c>
    <d/>
  </c>
</a>
```

and

```
<a>
  <c>
    <e/>
  </c>
</a>
```

In the first case there would have to be "b" element if "d" element would be found under "c" element. In the second case there would be NO "b" element allowed if there would be "e" under "c". So I'm looking for sort of this kind of solution:

```
<xsd:element name="a">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:all>
```

(

```
            <xsd:element name="b" type="whatever"/>
            <xsd:element name="c">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:all>
                        <xsd:element name="d" type="whatever"/>
                    </xsd:all>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element> )
```

) OR (

```
            <xsd:element name="c">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:all>
                        <xsd:element name="e" type="whatever"/>
                    </xsd:all>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
```

)

```
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

The reason I wouldn't want to use choice element is because I'm making an editor interface for an XML document and choice would simply look stupid in the editor interface in my case.

Comment: But `<xs:choice>` is _for_ “pick between”. That's its purpose.

Comment: Hmm. You're right now that I think of it. I've gotta do this thing differently.

Comment: But how can you put a choice on whole structures? I mean there would be more than one elements as option. The first choice would include b and c and second choice would only include c. I mean I don't want to enclose b and c inside a third element.

Comment: Looks like I can use group element: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_group.asp

Comment: Ok, actually I must have a sequence element inside the group element or only sequence without group. So a choice element would contain only sequence elements first of which would contain b and c (which would contain d) and the second would contain c (which would contain e). Phew. BTW: Is there any sensible reason why a choice element could not contain an all element (that would allow my b and c to be in any order)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm borrowing the thecolour's answer a bit. What I meant that I didn't want to my choice structure to be inside an element.

With the thecolour's answer a document like this would work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
<structure>
<a1>
<b>jkhgjhg</b>
<c>
<d>asdf</d>
</c>
</a1>
</structure>
</Root>
```

However the next schema works the way I want (The thecolour's answer has that extra "structure" element, too. I'm skipping that.):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://NS.Schema1" targetNamespace="http://NS.Schema1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
       <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" />
             <xs:element name="c">
                <xs:complexType>
                   <xs:all>
                      <xs:element name="d" type="xs:string" />
                   </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
             </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="c">
                <xs:complexType>
                   <xs:all>
                      <xs:element name="e" type="xs:string" />
                   </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
             </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
       </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This has the downside that in the first choice "b" and "c" elements have to be in that order. I don't know why you can't have "all" indicator inside "choice". Possibly because of how the schema parser works internally???

With this schema XML document like this works:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
<b>jkhgjhg</b>
<c>
<d>asdf</d>
</c>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is you would define two complex types to represent each "state" of your structure. Each complex type would apply different constraints to the nested elements within. Then you can simply group the two complex types as items under an xs:choice

Something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://NS.Schema1" targetNamespace="http://NS.Schema1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="structure">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
              <xs:element name="a1" type="a1" />
              <xs:element name="a2" type="a2" />
            </xs:choice>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="a1">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="c">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="d" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="a2">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="c">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="e" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

However, you cannot have the same root element name for both complex types.